# Flask-SocketIO Client automatically disconnects in 30 seconds

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I implemented a simple server to communicate with the client. About 30 seconds later, the server announced that the client was disconnected. I tried to increase the `ping_travler` and `ping_timeout` parameters of the server, but it didn't seem to help.

I want to know whether disconnection is caused by the server or the client. How can we keep the client and the server connected?

My code is as follows:

**server**:

```py
# coding:utf-8
import json
import socketio
import uvicorn

# ping_travler=60, ping_timeout=300, always_connect=True
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi')
app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio)

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect:', sid)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    sio.start_background_task(target=send_message)
    print("connect ", sid)

@sio.on('message', namespace='/server_conn')
async def receive_message(sid, data):
    pass

async def send_message():
    while True:
        await sio.sleep(0.00001)
        await sio.emit('receive_message', json.dumps('123'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

**client**:

```py
# coding:utf-8
import asyncio
import json
import time

from flask_socketio import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncClient(logger=True, engineio_logger=False)

t = time.time()

@sio.event
def connect():
    sio.start_background_task(target=send_message)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('client disconnected')


async def send_message():
    while True:
        await sio.sleep(0.2)
        await sio.send(json.dumps('123'), namespace='/server_rece')

@sio.event
async def receive_message(message):
    print(message)
    print(time.time() - t)  # Disconnected in about 30 seconds

async def start_sio_server():
    await sio.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000')

def main():
    LOOP = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(LOOP)
    LOOP.run_until_complete(start_sio_server())
    LOOP.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks.